# cocos2d-x selecting sprites while moving touch

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm new to cocos2d-x 3.6 and trying to make a simple game.

I have a vector of sprites. I want to touch one of them, and then move my finger across the screen and other sprites being selected while I'm touching them.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Do you mean sliding your finger, and that one finger selecting more than one, or do you mean with one finger down, the other keeps selecting sprites?

Comment: @TankorSmash   , I mean sliding finger and that one finger selecting more than one

Answer (score 0):

This sounds potentially performance intensive. The way I initially thought of is to implement a touch layer and you have to check if any sprite in the vector is hit by the touch in the touch moved event. If it is then you could add the sprite to another "selected" vector or something. This check would be performed every step, which sounds very not-good.

Something like this, but you would have to check for every sprite in the vector:
http://wizardfu.com/book/cocos2d-x/touch-tutorial-player-movement/

I have an idea for another method that I'm not sure will work, so you'll have to try. Attach a touch handler on each sprite and in those handlers, deal with the selection logic. However, I don't know:

1. if this method is actually even more efficient than the first method in reality. I don't know how these node touch events are computed.
2. if a node's touch moved event even fires when it didn't start on the node.

But you add the node's touch events like this: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners

For some reason they didn't add the moved or cancelled events, but they exist.